# JAX-WS is not injecting WebServiceContext

Tags: web-services, jboss, jax-ws, jboss5.x

I created a web-service using `JAX-WS` and `JBOSS 5.1.0`. At the top of my service class I put:

```
@Resource
private WebServiceContext context;
```

But when I try to access `context` in any of my webservice methods, I get `NullPointerException` because context is `null`. Does anyone has an idea why `JAX-WS` is not setting it correctly and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Look for `resteasy.scan.resources` in the following link: https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.0.GA/userguide/html/Installation_Configuration.html

Comment: Where is the code of the class you're injecting it into? Do you have any other annotations on the class that may result in the class being proxied?

Answer (score 0):

Me too was getting a null. If you are using Spring, add this:

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
```

it worked for me.